# What is causing my segfault when indexing this 2D vector?

Tags: c++

When I am indexing the 2D vector `scoremap` with the line: `int tile = this->scoremap[x][y];`, I am getting a segfault. Can anyone explain what I may be doing wrong?

```
#include "minesweeper.h"

using namespace std;

Minesweeper::Minesweeper() {
    // Easy difficulty default values
    map_size = 5;
    mines = 8;
    score = 0;

    // Create displaymap & scoremap based on map_size
    // displaymap is chars, initialized to quesiton marks (?)
    // scoremap is ints, initliazed to zeros (0)
    vector<vector<char>> displaymap(map_size, vector<char>(map_size, '?'));
    vector<vector<int>> scoremap(map_size, vector<int>(map_size, 0));
};

// Generate mines / score tiles on the scoremap
void Minesweeper::generate_scoremap() {

    // First, generate mines on map
    int mine_count = this->mines;
    // While we have mines to place
    while (mine_count != 0) {
        // Get a random position on the map
        pair<int,int> position = random_position(this->map_size);
        int x = position.first;
        int y = position.second;

        // If it's not already a mine (mines = -1, other tiles = how many mines are touching the tile)
        int tile = this->scoremap[x][y];
        if (tile != -1) {
            tile = -1;
            this->scoremap[x][y] = tile;
            mine_count--;
        }
        else {
            // find a new spot for this mine
        }
    }

    // Next, set score of each tile that isn't a mine
    // Direciton pairs for checking adjacent tiles
    vector<std::pair<int, int>> directions = 
    {
        {-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1},
        {0, -1},            {0, 1},
        {1, -1},  {1, 0},  {1, 1}
    };

    // Check each tile and set its score
    for (int i = 0; i < this->map_size; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < this->map_size; j++) {
            int tilescore = 0;

            // Check to make sure it isn't a mine
            if (this->scoremap[i][j] != -1) {

            // Check all adjacent cells for mines
                for (const auto& dir : directions) {
                    int newi = i + dir.first;
                    int newj = j + dir.second;

                    // If the index is in the map
                    if (index_valid(newi,newj,this->map_size)) {

                        // and its a mine, increase tile score
                        if (this->scoremap[newi][newj] == -1) {
                            tilescore++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            // Set tile score on scoremap
            this->scoremap[i][j] = tilescore;
            tilescore = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried manually creating the 2D vector with the right characters and right size, and it seems to work, but I would like the 2D vector to be generated dynamically according to whatever the `map_size` variable is (here it's set automatically in the constructor, but later I would like it to be a value from the user, or from picking a specific difficulty level).

Comment: This would follow C++ conventions more closely if you used a constructor list. Also consider abandoning `using namespace std` as that causes a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Minesweeper`'s constructor is creating *local variables* that shadow the *member variables* of the same names.  So, you are not actually putting any data into the member variables that you can then index into later.

Try this instead:

```
Minesweeper::Minesweeper()
    // Easy difficulty default values
    map_size = 5;
    mines = 8;
    score = 0;

    // Create displaymap & scoremap based on map_size
    // displaymap is chars, initialized to quesiton marks (?)
    // scoremap is ints, initliazed to zeros (0)
    displaymap.resize(map_size, vector<char>(map_size, '?'));
    scoremap.resize(map_size, vector<int>(map_size, 0));
};
```